# iPad's UIActionSheet showing multiple times

Tags: ipad, uibarbuttonitem, uiactionsheet

I have a method called -showMoreTools: which is:

```
- (IBAction) showMoreTools:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"Add Bookmark", @"Add to Home Screen", @"Print", @"Share", nil];
    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    popupQuery.dismiss
    [popupQuery showFromBarButtonItem:moreTools animated:YES];
    [popupQuery release];
}
```

When an user taps a `UIBarButtonItem` it displays that `UIActionSheet`, but then, if the user wants to close the `UIActionSheet` without taping the Close button, (taping the `UIBarButtonItem`, then it displays the `UIActionSheet` over the first `UIActionSheet`.

It's possible to implement somehow taping another time the `UIBarButtonItem` to close the `UIActionSheet`?

Thank you so much – I'm a newbie in iOS Programming!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In order to dismiss it when you click on the button twice, you need to keep track of the currently displaying ActionSheet. We do this in our iPad app and it works great.

In your class that has the showMoreTools, in the header put:

```
@interface YourClassHere : NSObject <UIActionSheetDelegate> {
      UIActionSheet* actionSheet_;  // add this line
}
```

In the class file, change it to:

```
-(IBAction) showMoreTools:(id)sender {
    // currently displaying actionsheet?
    if (actionSheet_) {
        [actionSheet_ dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
        actionSheet_ = nil;
        return;
    }

    actionSheet_ = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"Add Bookmark", @"Add to Home Screen", @"Print", @"Share", nil];
    actionSheet_.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [popupQuery showFromBarButtonItem:moreTools animated:YES];
    [actionSheet_ release];  // yes, release it. we don't retain it and don't need to
}


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // just set to nil
    actionSheet_ = nil;
}
```

Comment: Solution worked well for me when I had the same problem, thanks.  I wonder why Apple don't mention this, because they are explicitly making it happen when it "adds the toolbar that owns the button to the popover’s list of passthrough views"

Comment: Also I think you would have set actionSheet_ to nil in actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:

Comment: You don't need to. If you select a button,  the clickedButtonAtIndex is called, and then afterwards the  didDismissWithButtonIndex is also called. Putting the =nil is only required in that one method. I just double checked it in the debugger.

Comment: Just happened to bump into one case where Bryan is correct. When I pop an `UIAlertView` from `UIActionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex` `didDismissWithButtonIndex`is not called.

Comment: Condition `if (actionSheet_)` can be replaced with `if ([actionSheet_ superview])`. I used DTActionSheet from [DTFoundation](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTFoundation), so overriding cancel was not suitable for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution to this. The problem is that when using `showFromBarButtonItem`, the toolbar view is automatically added to the popover's list of passthrough views. You can modify (and clear) the passthrough views when using a `UIPopoverController` directly, but not when it's presented as part of a `UIActionSheet`.

Anyway, by using `showFromRect`, there is no toolbar that the popover can automatically add to its passthrough views. So if you know the (approximate) rectangle where your button bar is, you can use something like:

```
CGRect buttonRect = CGRectIntersection(toolbar.frame, CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, self.frame.size.height));
[popupQuery showFromRect:buttonRect inView:self animated:YES];
```

In the above example, my button is on the left hand side of the toolbar.

Comment: One problem with this approach is that if you support rotation you're responsible for managing the popover's position after the rotate.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 0):

try by setting the flag(YES/NO)

```
-(void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: u mean if actionsheet is visible set Yes. On clicking on another button check for actionsheet is visible are not right...

Answer (score 0):

My method is similar to christophercotton's.

In my showActionSheet I check if the actionsheet is visible rather than instantiated:

```
- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.fullActionSheet isVisible]) {
        [self.fullActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:NO];
        _fullActionSheet = nil;
        return;
    }

    //actionsheet code
}
```